# iPhone: Button "Vote in AppStore"

Tags: objective-c, iphone, app-store

I would like to add a button "Vote Us" that opens App Store and brings automatically users to **my app review page** where they can vote my app.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
     @"http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=YOUR_APP_ID&mt=8"
]];
```

Comment: getting alert .. "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to access specific pages on the App Store is to use the URLs, which are opened automatically on the iPhone using the Store app.  For example, sending the user to http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/polytune/id364009203?mt=8 takes them to the PolyTune page in the App Store.  I'm not sure if there is a more direct way to achieve it.

Comment: ok, but I see some apps redirecting directly to the review page

Comment: Okay, try using this link to go direct: ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=364009203

Replace the id with you app's id, but keep the Purple+Software part.  This should take the user to the reviews section, but they still have to click the "Write Review" button themselves.  As far as I'm aware that's as direct as you can go.

Comment: great it works! but you have also to use &mt=8 to go directly to appstore. see my answer for the full answer